# Why might SOLIDWORKS PDM API CreateFolderPath be initially slow?

Tags: solidworkspdmapi

I'm using the PDM API CreateFolderPath to create all folders in a path (if they do not already exist), to where I will later save a file to.  I find that the initial loop of the code runs about 13000ms on this line of code, while subsequent iterations run only 600ms each.  Is this typical? is there a way to address it?

IEdmFolder5 rootFolder = vault.RootFolder;
IEdmFolder5 targetFolder = rootFolder.CreateFolderPath($@"folder1{var1}{var2}\folder4", parentWindowHandle);

I added stopwatches in various places, and found it came down to just the CreateFolderPath line.
Additionally, I tried adding in a vault.LoginAuto but that did not correct the delay.